# Кроссбраузерный текст под углом

Tags: css3, jquery, html5

Для того, чтобы в верстке сделать текст под углом, использую свойство CSS3 transform, точнее, его вендорные аналоги

```
-moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
-webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
-o-transform: rotate(-45deg);
-ms-transform: rotate(-45deg); /* для IE9 */
transform: rotate(-45deg);
```

Для того, чтобы всe отображалось в IE<=8, используется скрипт

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            if (($.browser.msie == true)&($.browser.version<=8)) 
        {
            var deg2radians = Math.PI*2/360,
            deg = -45;
            rad = deg * deg2radians,
            costheta = Math.cos(rad),
            sintheta = Math.sin(rad);

            $('.currentDate p').css({
                    filter: 'progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Matrix(M11='+costheta+', M12='+(-1)*sintheta+', M21='+sintheta+', M22='+costheta+', SizingMethod="auto expand", enabled=true)'
                });
        };

        });
    </script>
```

В ие8 он у меня работает, в ие7 - нет.
Сделано всё по [этой статье](http://www.xiper.net/collect/html-and-css-tricks/typographics/inclined-text.html) с xiper.net, но [демо-пример](http://www.xiper.net/examples/html-and-css-tricks/typographics/inclined-text.html) оттуда в ие7 работает, а [моя верстка](http://web-portfolio1.narod.ru/index6/index.html) - нет. Подскажите, в чем дело?

Answer (score 2):

Кажется разобрался. Проблема заключается в вёрстке.

Для тега с классом **.currentDate** необходимо указать ширину. К примеру,

```
.currentDate {
   width: 250px;
}
```

Проверил в IE6-8 - всё отлично отображается.

**P.S.** В IE8 и без указания ширины текст отображался с наклоном, но почему-то уезжал вниз.

**P.P.S.** Просьба переменные в JS во избежании проблем с областью видимости, указывать через запятую.

```
deg = -45;
```

на

```
deg = -45,
```

Также, все текстовые значения json-массива указывать в кавычках

Заменить

```
filter:
```

на

```
 "filter":
```

Comment: в ие7 все равно не работает.

Comment: За неимением IE7, проверял свой проект через Adobe Browserlab, всё хорошо отображается. В IE6 отлично.

Телефон на плече справа:

[http://dev-web.tw1.ru/][1]


  [1]: http://dev-web.tw1.ru/

Разница лишь в повороте - у меня на 20 град.

Comment: @Heidel Думаю, разобрался. Отредактировал ответ.

Comment: Большое спасибо! всё отлично получилось!